got expection while working on flutter with Agora using agora_rtc_engine: ^6.3.0
Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'libiris_method_channel.so': dlopen failed: library "libiris_method_channel.so" not found
E/flutter ( 3573): #0      _open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:11:43)
E/flutter ( 3573): #1      new DynamicLibrary.open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:22:12)
E/flutter ( 3573): #2      _loadLib (package:iris_method_channel/src/platform/io/iris_event_io.dart:16:31)
E/flutter ( 3573): #3      new IrisEventIO (package:iris_method_channel/src/platform/io/iris_event_io.dart:26:54)
E/flutter ( 3573): #4      IrisMethodChannelInternalIO._execute (package:iris_method_channel/src/platform/io/iris_method_channel_internal_io.dart:421:64)
E/flutter ( 3573): #5      _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:300:17)
E/flutter ( 3573): #6      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
E/flutter ( 3573): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 3573): #0      _HotRestartFinalizer._finalize (package:iris_method_channel/src/platform/io/iris_method_channel_internal_io.dart:155:74)
E/flutter ( 3573): #1      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
E/flutter ( 3573): #2      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter ( 3573): #3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter ( 3573): #4      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784:19)
E/flutter ( 3573): #5      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658:7)
E/flutter ( 3573): #6      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606:5)
E/flutter ( 3573): #7      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
E/flutter ( 3573):
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/agora_rtc_engine.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';





class newww extends StatefulWidget {
  const newww({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<newww> createState() => _newwwState();
}

class _newwwState extends State<newww> {
  int? _remoteUid;
  bool _localUserJoined = false;
  late RtcEngine _engine;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }

  Future<void> initAgora() async {
    // retrieve permissions
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();

    //create the engine
    _engine = createAgoraRtcEngine();
    await _engine.initialize(const RtcEngineContext(
      appId: "a28be509a7404ebc9f42459393ba1cfa",
      channelProfile: ChannelProfileType.channelProfileLiveBroadcasting,
    ));

    _engine.registerEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        onJoinChannelSuccess: (RtcConnection connection, int elapsed) {
          debugPrint("local user ${connection.localUid} joined");
          setState(() {
            _localUserJoined = true;
          });
        },
        onUserJoined: (RtcConnection connection, int remoteUid, int elapsed) {
          debugPrint("remote user $remoteUid joined");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = remoteUid;
          });
        },
        onUserOffline: (RtcConnection connection, int remoteUid,
            UserOfflineReasonType reason) {
          debugPrint("remote user $remoteUid left channel");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = null;
          });
        },
        onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire: (RtcConnection connection, String token) {
          debugPrint(
              '[onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire] connection: ${connection.toJson()}, token: $token');
        },
      ),
    );

    await _engine.setClientRole(role: ClientRoleType.clientRoleBroadcaster);
    await _engine.enableVideo();
    await _engine.startPreview();

    await _engine.joinChannel(
      token: "007eJxTYDBL3aC4U2Hicl9Vsc4Eo0bx4z8K4u59u6EaeHiuVIObhK8CQ6KRRVKqqYFlormJgUlqUrJlmomRiamlsaVxUqJhclri6dXaaQ2BjAxJsreYGBkgEMRnYShJLS5hYAAAzAceCQ==",
      channelId: "test",
      uid: 0,
      options: const ChannelMediaOptions(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    _dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _dispose() async {
    await _engine.leaveChannel();
    await _engine.release();
  }

  // Create UI with local view and remote view
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Agora Video Call'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: _remoteVideo(),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              height: 150,
              child: Center(
                child: _localUserJoined
                    ? AgoraVideoView(
                  controller: VideoViewController(
                    rtcEngine: _engine,
                    canvas: const VideoCanvas(uid: 0),
                  ),
                )
                    : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Display remote user's video
  Widget _remoteVideo() {
    if (_remoteUid != null) {
      return AgoraVideoView(
        controller: VideoViewController.remote(
          rtcEngine: _engine,
          canvas: VideoCanvas(uid: _remoteUid),
          connection: const RtcConnection(channelId: "test"),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return const Text(
        'Please wait for remote user to join',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }
}



Here the solution which is working for me (found here: https://github.com/dart-lang/native/issues/897)
1. In Xcode, go to **Target Runner > Build Settings > Strip Style**.
2. Change from **All Symbols** to **Non-Global Symbols**.

Also, this issue happens with a real device and doesn't happen with iPhone emulator.
